# Find the GCD of two numbers without using divison or mod operator?

Tags: c, algorithm, numbers

I want to find GCD of two numbers but without using division or mod operator.
one obvious way would be to write own mod function like this:

```
enter code here
int mod(int a, int b)
{
   while(a>b)
       a-=b;

return a;
}
```

and then use this function in the euclid algorithm.
Any other way ??

Comment: Why do you need that? it's extremly inefficient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the substraction based version of [euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations) up front:

```
function gcd(a, b)
    if a = 0
       return b
    while b ≠ 0
        if a > b
           a := a − b
        else
           b := b − a
    return a
```

Comment: @H2CO3 This is what I would have been posting too. What we *should* have been posting is Bobby Dizzles's version below.

Answer (score 10):

What you are looking for is the Binary GCD algorithm:

```
public class BinaryGCD {

    public static int gcd(int p, int q) {
        if (q == 0) return p;
        if (p == 0) return q;

        // p and q even
        if ((p & 1) == 0 && (q & 1) == 0) return gcd(p >> 1, q >> 1) << 1;

        // p is even, q is odd
        else if ((p & 1) == 0) return gcd(p >> 1, q);

        // p is odd, q is even
        else if ((q & 1) == 0) return gcd(p, q >> 1);

        // p and q odd, p >= q
        else if (p >= q) return gcd((p-q) >> 1, q);

        // p and q odd, p < q
        else return gcd(p, (q-p) >> 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int p = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int q = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        System.out.println("gcd(" + p + ", " + q + ") = " + gcd(p, q));
    }
}
```

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm

Comment: This is basically a bitwise way to implement mod and divisions :|

Comment: This is mind-blowing. How the heck did it get downvoted? (apart from the fact that until one carefully reads the cases “p and q odd”, it looks like it cannot possibly work, perhaps)

Answer (score 0):

Recursive GCD computing using subtraction:

```
int GCD(int a, int b)
{
    int gcd = 0;
    if(a < 0)
    {
        a = -a;
    }
    if(b < 0)
    {
        b = -b;
    }
    if (a == b)
    {
        gcd = a;
        return gcd;
    }
    else if (a > b)
    {
        return GCD(a-b,b);
    }
    else
    {
        return GCD(a,b-a);
    }
}
```

Source: [link](http://i-nfiniteloop.blogspot.ro/2012/10/finding-greatest-common-divisor-of-two.html)

Answer (score -1):

A more or less direct way is the following code, which is derived from Pick's theorem:

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{

     if( a < 0)
     {
         a = -a;
     }

     if( b < 0)
     {
         b = -b;
     }

     if( a == b)
     {
          return a;
     }

     //swap the values to make the upper bound in the next loop minimal
     if( a > b)
     {
        int swap = a;
        a = b;
        b = swap;
     }
     

     int temp=0;

     for(int i=1; i<=a; i++)
     {
          temp += math.floor(b*i/a);
     }

     return (a*b + b - a + temp)/2;
}
```

Comment: The question specifically asked for an implementation that doesn't use division.

Comment: If one like use a division function based on subtraction.